# Cordova / Ionic iOS app hangs on splash screen while loading plugins

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Our app is currently crashing for all users on iOS 11. The app loads the splash screen and then hangs infinitely. This issue does not effect users not using iOS 11 and is not reproducible on the iOS 11 simulator.

The only clues we have for this issue are that when we inspect the code using Safari Developer Tools we can see that it is the plugins that are failing to load. This issue is not reproducible 100% of the time but it is about 98% of the time.

Here is the only error we see in Xcode:

```
[BoringSSL] Function nw_protocol_boringssl_input_finished: line 1389 Peer disconnected during the middle of a handshake. Sending errSSLFatalAlert(-9802) alert
TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x1c016b4c0]: 3:-9802 Err(-9802)
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
Task <F69566CA-B83A-4252-B2F2-DDB84A7AAFD3>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9802])
Task <F69566CA-B83A-4252-B2F2-DDB84A7AAFD3>.<1> finished with error - code: -1200
```

and here is a screenshot of how it looks when we debug in the browser: (all other resources off the screen load fine)
[image]

This error started occurring right after iOS 11 was released and we have not changed any code. Help would be greatly appreciated as this error appears to be coming from inside of Cordova.

Note: We are using Cordova 4.3.1 and tried updating to the latest but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to our issue was to remove the plugin `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently have been experiencing this issue.  I'm using the new CLI 9.0 and iOS 5.0.  I actually removed the splashscreen plugin and it worked.  And a side benefit is it is a heck of a lot faster too!